# PowerBI refresh fails with CosmosDB catalog

Tags: powerbi, databricks, azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

I have a Power BI report that has a Databricks table with a direct connection to CosmosDB based con the CosmosCatalog plugin. Here is the weird thing: when the Databricks cluster is off, and the report is starting to refresh, the cluster is obviously started but the report refresh fails with the following error:

```
Error from server: error code: '0' error message: 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: 
[_LEGACY_ERROR_TEMP_2215] org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot find catalog plugin class for catalog 'cosmosCatalog': com.azure.cosmos.spark.CosmosCatalog (...). 
The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. Table: table_foo.
```

But, after I query that `table_foo` directly in Databricks, and then come back to PowerBI and refresh the query, now it works.

Why the CosmosCatalog fails at first but works after querying the table in Databricks. Does Databricks plugins don't initializate before being directly used?